# Javascript match

Tags: javascript, match

How could I get the numbers of this string: `'(31.5393701, -82.46235569999999)'`

I'm already trying something but this is far away from the solution :)

```
text.match(/\((\d+),(\d+)\)/);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `string.split`

e.g:

```
var nums = text.replace(/[^0-9-,.+]/, "").split(","); 
var num1 = parseFloat(nums[0]);
var num2 = parseFloat(nums[1]);
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AL3e4/

Answer (score 1):

```
var text =  '(31.5393701, -82.46235569999999)';
var matches = text.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',');
if (matches.length > 1) {
    var lat = Number(matches[0]);
    var lon = Number(matches[1]);
    alert(lat + ' ' + lon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
text.replace("(","").replace(")").replace(" ").split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  pretty close, but missing the sign, the decimal digits and some spaces. If you need to capture that from a string, try this:

```
/\(([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
text.match(/\(([\d.-]+),\s+([\d.-]+)\)/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"(31.5393701, -82.46235569999999)".replace(/\(|\)/g, '').split(', ');
```